# XAML - How do I programmatically create a Path from mini-markup?

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml

I have some mini markup describing a shape. In XAML, I can use this string directly in XAML or via a binding or resource, but how can I programmatically use this markup? The problem is that no geometry or shape API in the framework seems to accept a string.

I remember struggling with this same problem in 2008. Has nothing changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ho hum. I found this workaround.

```
Path o = (Path)XamlReader.Load(String.Format(@"<Path xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"" Data=""{0}"" />", pathData));
```

Comment: That's fine, unless you're asking for binding some point/edge.

Comment: If you only want to programmatically create the path `Geometry` from the mini-markup, you can also use: `Geometry.Parse(pathData);`